# SQL Server inefficient query (server full load)

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-performance

We are currently scraping structured data from a variety of different sources. Before ingesting new data into our table, we check to see if the data_id exists already.

`IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE DATA_ID=@P0)`

We have no indexes; however, we have a PK set for our id column which seems unnecessary, should we remove this to improve insert speed?

Our server is currently at full load checking through 3 million or so worth of data to make sure we are not inserting duplicate data. We have tried upgrading our SQL Server for higher DTU but that doesn't seem to help at all.

When we have multiple jobs running at the same time checking for unique data or SQL Server comes to a crawl and insert speed takes forever.

Should we get rid of this unique data check and create new tables for every scraping job, then use a SQL Query to compare the differences, such as new data or data that was removed?

Query used for conditional insertion:

```
String sql = "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM A_PROV_CVV_LDG_1 WHERE DATA_ID=?) " +
            "INSERT INTO A_PROV_CVV_LDG_1 (DATA_ID, SourceID, BASE_ID, BIN, BANK, CARD_TYPE, CARD_CLASS," +
            " CARD_LEVEL, CARD_EXP, COUNTRY, STATE, CITY, ZIP, DOB, SSN, EMAIL, PHONE, GENDER, ADDR_LINE_1, ADDR_LINE_2," +
            " FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, DateAddedToMarket, PRICE) " +
            "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

This is the entire table definition, no indexes only PK is 'id' which seems unnecessary.

`+-------------------+--------------+-----------+
| (PK)id            | int          | Unchecked |
| DATA_ID           | int          | Checked   |
| SourceID          | int          | Checked   |
| BASE_ID           | varchar(255) | Checked   |
| BIN               | varchar(255) | Checked   |
| BANK              | varchar(255) | Checked   |
| CARD_TYPE         | varchar(255) | Checked   |
| CARD_CLASS        | varchar(255) | Checked   |
| CARD_LEVEL        | varchar(255) | Checked   |
| CARD_EXP          | varchar(255) | Checked   |
| COUNTRY           | varchar(255) | Checked   |
| STATE             | varchar(255) | Checked   |
| CITY              | varchar(255) | Checked   |
| ZIP               | varchar(255) | Checked   |
| DOB               | varchar(255) | Checked   |
| SSN               | varchar(255) | Checked   |
| EMAIL             | varchar(255) | Checked   |
| PHONE             | varchar(255) | Checked   |
| GENDER            | varchar(255) | Checked   |
| ADDR_LINE_1       | varchar(255) | Checked   |
| ADDR_LINE_2       | varchar(255) | Checked   |
| FIRST_NAME        | varchar(255) | Checked   |
| LAST_NAME         | varchar(255) | Checked   |
| PRICE             | varchar(255) | Checked   |
| DateAddedToMarket | varchar(255) | Checked   |
| DateAdded         | datetime     | Unchecked |
+-------------------+--------------+-----------+`

Comment: I imagine removing the `top 1` will help, since it doesn't need to do any sorting anymore. `TOP 1` is redundant, since you are looking to see if any record exists, one or multiple doesn't matter.

Comment: Research SQL merge function. I am not very familiar with it personally but I reckon you can use that to improve the efficiency.

Comment: I agree with @LJ01    `Merge` is best option and would drastically improve performance compared to using `Not Exists`, if you like help with Merge script, we can help

Comment: Please show us the entire query you use for conditional insertion. Also please show us the entire table definition including keys and any indexes. Is your PK on the  `DATA_ID` column? If not, you need an index on that column.

Comment: @O.Jones Updated for you, includes all the info you asked. I have heard that indexing decreases insert performance?

Comment: what are common fields between source and destination , `id or Data_id`. It doesnt matter if u have indexes or not in destination table with `Merge', you will need at least one matching non nullable column

Comment: @BHouse data_id, the id column is really just trivial and doesn't matter much to us.

Comment: So, if u have linked server connection , why not try `merge` using `Data_id` as join column.

Comment: @BHouse I will look into merge, very new to this all.

Comment: @EmilioPagan-Yourno add your source table and destination table, i will provide sample script

Comment: Is the problem in _select_ ing or _insert_ ing? first work that out

Comment: merge is just combined insret/delete/update. It's really no better abdin fact makes it harder to isolate performance issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You absolutely need a unique index on `DATA_ID` for your query--indeed for any deduplication attempt on `DATA_ID`---to work efficiently. Without it every attempted insert does a full table scan.

Yes, indexes slow down insertion a little bit. But an index on an integer column isn't very expensive. Certainly not compared to the mess you're in now with a table scan for every insertion. Create that index.

Comment: Thank you. Should I have an index on SourceID as well? Sometimes data_id is the same for different SourceID and I wouldn't want to miss out on inserting new data.

Comment: You need an index on whatever you have in real life for `IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE DATA_ID=@P0)` . The point is to make that `SELECT` operation efficient. If it's `WHERE DATA_ID=@p0 AND SOURCE_ID=@p1`, then a compound index on those columns will be helpful. Read this https://use-the-index-luke.com/

Answer (score 1):

If the server is busy, the statement: IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE DATA_ID=@P0) might be blocked or disk requests are queued. Run sp_who2 to check if there is blocking. If this is the only routine that puts data in the table add WITH (NOLOCK), selecting Null instead of anything unnecessary:

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT null FROM TABLE_NAME WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE DATA_ID=@P0)

Comment: Can I run sp_who2 on SQL Azure?

Comment: Yes. The same DMV tables are on Azure, so sp_who2 will work.

Answer (score 0):

This construct:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM A_PROV_CVV_LDG_1 WHERE DATA_ID=?)
    INSERT INTO A_PROV_CVV_LDG_1 . . .
```

is an anti-pattern.  It is attempting to prevent duplicates in code.  However, it suffers from race conditions.  And you should let the database implement data integrity checks, where it can.

Instead, implement a unique constraint/index to prevent duplicates:

```
alter table A_PROV_CVV_LDG_1 add constraint unq_A_PROV_CVV_LDG_1_data_id
    unique (data_id);
```

This does mean that you need to catch an error if you try to insert a duplicate value.  That is easy enough in SQL Server using `try`/`catch` blocks.

Comment: I'm not familiar with try/catch blocks, but will look this up. Thank you!